# Security group 'ALB-sg' is not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I create an ALB by Cfn, but I got the error called

Security group 'ALB-sg' is not valid (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 6ec8a268-80cc-4a3e-9477-809dba8a00c7; Proxy: null)

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Description: AWS CloudFormation Sample Template for creating LoadBalancer

Parameters:
  VPC:
    Description: VPCId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)
    Type: String
    Default: vpc-0c9a732125ac08541
  
  PublicSubnet:
    Description: SubnetId of an existing subnet (for the primary network in your Virtual Private Cloud VPC)
    Type: String
    Default: subnet-0787f34404852ceb9

Resources:
  
  ApplicationLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties: 
      Name: MyApplicationLoadBalancer
      Type: application
      IpAddressType: ipv4
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups: 
        - !Ref Albsg 
      Subnets: 
        - !Ref PublicSubnet
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: ALB

  HTTPListener:
        Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener"
        Properties:
            LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ApplicationLoadBalancer
            Port: 80
            Protocol: "HTTP"
            DefaultActions: 
              - Type: forward
                TargetGroupArn: !Ref ALBTargetGroup
  
  
  ALBTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
      HealthCheckPath: /
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: 200,302
      Name: MyWebServers
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: instance
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 5
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      

  Albsg:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupName: ALB-sg
      GroupDescription: Security group for Load balancer
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: '80'
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: '80'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name 
          Value: ALB_SG

Outputs:
  TargetGroupName:
    Value: !Ref ALBTargetGroup
    Description: Name of Target ARN
```

I am not sure what else to try. Here is the template I am working with..

Answer (score 1):

In the `SecurityGroupIngress` of the `Albsg`, the fields `FromPort` and `ToPort` have to be integers, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

The string `ALB-sg` only appears one place in your template, so that is obviously where the error is:

```
GroupName: ALB-sg
```

I'm thinking the `-` character is throwing it off. You should simply wrap the value in quotes:

```
GroupName: "ALB-sg"
```